# Need to resize the Delete button when row is swiped

Tags: uitableview

I have a UITableView that when I swipe the row, the Delete button appears.  The problem is that the Delete button is not wide enough to hide a piece of data behind it, which makes it look amateurish.

How can I fix this (widen the button)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the name of the button and add spaces in there.

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return @"  Delete  ";
}
```

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that?  (I do it all the time with my own buttons for alignment!)  Thank you so much... I really appreciate it!

Comment: Uhhh... I'm working in Monotouch, and I don't see any exposed methods or properties like you mentioned.  How do I find the right property?

Comment: I just moved the cell that was partially visible... thanks for your help tho'